# Can't use docker-compose despite I installed it

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I installed Docker-machine and Docker-compose in my container via the Dockefile:

```
RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.9.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine && \
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine    
RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

but I can only use docker-machine.
When I want to use docker-compose it says:

```
bash-4.3# ls /usr/local/bin/
docker-compose docker-machine
bash-4.3# stat /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
File: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
Size: 8273264 Blocks: 16160 IO Block: 4096 regular file
Device: fd09h/64777d Inode: 29362189 Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x) Uid: ( 0/ root) Gid: ( 0/ root)
Access: 2017-05-23 07:14:43.000000000
Modify: 2017-05-23 07:08:17.000000000
Change: 2017-05-23 07:14:23.000000000
bash-4.3# docker-compose
bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory
```

any ideas ?
[EDIT] The docker-machine who works perfectly has the same right:

```
bash-4.3# stat  /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
  File: /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
  Size: 25287328    Blocks: 49392      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd09h/64777d    Inode: 29362188    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-05-23 07:14:28.000000000
Modify: 2017-05-23 07:08:07.000000000
Change: 2017-05-23 07:14:22.000000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was solved with https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Docker#Docker_Compose and the help of [www.reddit.com/u/moojo](https://www.reddit.com/user/moojo)